# How to setup version for differential views?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I want differential view based on version , how to assign version to my current set of issues / analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Issues cannot be assigned a version.

Issues are tied to a project & the project has a version. Let's say it's currently 1.0. 
When you update the project version to 1.1, you'll then be able to distinguish issues created *since `previous_version`*.

To set up the differential, just look at the interface, it will guide you in your options:

> - Number of days before analysis, for example 5.
> - A custom date. Format is yyyy-MM-dd, for example 2010-12-25
> - previous_analysis' to compare to previous analysis
> - 'previous_version' to compare to the previous version in the project history
> - A version, for example '1.2' or'BASELINE'

Comment: But how sonar find's  previous version , basically I want to tag my current technical debt to a version , so that for future check in I can find differential debt with tagged version/ release